# How to remove .firebaseapp.com when Google authentication

Tags: firebase-authentication

[image: image of URL]

Hi recently we have added Google signup to our website so when user clicks on login with google,it generats url with firsebaseapp in url link. How hide that firebaseapp word in url please help

Comment: When you include images, leave the template and it will include your image in your question, as you can see after I edited your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.